# RCassandra is not connecting to Cassandra Database

Tags: r, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and R. When I'm connecting to Cassandra database using `RCassandra` package, connection is establishing. But When trying to use any keyspace, R is not responding. I used the following statements.

```
c <- RC.connect('192.168.1.20', 9042)
RC.use(c, 'effesensors')
```

Please give me a brief idea about how to use `RCassandra` to avoid this problem.

Comment: When you say "trying to use any keyspace" what exactly do you mean? Are you trying to select from it? Or perform an insert/delete? Also, are you able to use Cassandra's Command Line Interface (CLI) to connect to the Cassandra cluster?

Comment: invoking the **RC.use(c, 'effesensors')** statement made RStudio to the state "Not Responding".

Comment: What about running a query in the Cassandra CLI?

Comment: I'm using cqlsh. Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of RODBC instead of using RCassandra. We need to install Cassandra ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you may be using a non default port for Cassandra? If you can provide the Cassandra version and RStudio version I may be able to update my answer. I found [this tutorial](http://blog.tarkalabs.com/2014/09/22/how-to-rcassandra/) by tarkalabs useful as a checklist of steps to take before any connection is attempted.

From the tutorial,

> Now connect to your database with `connect.handle <-
>   RC.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=9160)`
>
> Cassandra by default listens to port 9160 but you can change it
>   according to your configuration. To show the cluster type into your
>   prompt `RC.cluster.name(connect.handle)`

Just to verify that you are connected and your Cassandra instance is running try the following command:
`RC.describe.keyspaces(connect.handle)`

That should bring back a list of the settings in your keyspaces. If nothing returns, you are either not connected or your Cassandra instance is not properly installed.

EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
$system_traces$strategy_options
replication_factor 
               "2" 

$system_traces$cf_defs
named list()

$system_traces$durable_writes
[1] TRUE
```

Let me know what your results are if my answer does not work and I will update my answer. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Nathan. I performed the same thing earlier, but I'm facing the Problem. I'm Using RStudio Version 0.99.489. R Version 3.2.2(32-Bit). RCassandra Version 0.1-3. Datastax Cassandra Server 2.2.3(64-Bit). Cassandra Server was Installed in another System.

Comment: Are you or the other system located behind a proxy?

Comment: No.. RC.connect('192.168.1.20', 9042) is giving
<pointer: 0x10f5dd80>
attr(,"class")
[1] "CassandraConnection"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @D. Venkata Naresh, your suggestion of using RODBC driver resolved my issue.

I am using R and datastax cassandra community edition.

This is the link I followed to configure the ODBC driver in my windows machine.

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-datastax-odbc-driver-for-apache-cassandra

Then, in my R studio, These are the commands to connect and fetch from the Cassandra

```
    install.packages("RODBC")
library("RODBC")
require("RODBC")

conn <- odbcConnect(<ODBC datasource name>)

dataframe <- sqlFetch(conn, <column family / table name>)

dataframe
```

Hope, this answer helps someone who is facing issue with RCassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I read your comments above, you are using the wrong port. You should run the following command
c <- RC.connect('192.168.1.20', 9160)
This will definitely work for you.